# CMake compile time generation of source

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the following situation with CMake:

1. it has to build two applications:

   a. **generator**

   b. **something_else**
2. The **generator** is nothing fancy, a few CPP files linked together
3. The **something_else** is:

   a. a few "normal" CPP files

   b. generated CPP/h files which I have to link in. These CPP files are generated by the **generator**

The **generator** is configured in the configure phase with some choices, depending on these options the content of the generated files is different.

And here I get an error: If I specify all the files (generated and not) in the `add_application` of **something_else** the configure phase chokes on it since it cannot find the generated files... obviously because they were not generated yet, since the **generator** was not built and executed yet.

So the question: Is this possible using CMake? If yes, how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You do that by providing a custom command to generate the files, so that CMake learns how to generate them. Here's an example:

```
add_executable(generator gen1.cpp gen2.cpp)

add_custom_command(
  OUTPUT generated_file1.cpp generated_file2.cpp
  COMMAND generator -options --go here
  COMMENT "Running generator"
  VERBATIM
)

add_executable(something_else
  fixed1.cpp
  fixed2.cpp
  generated_file1.cpp
  generated_file2.cpp
)
```

This way, CMake will know the files are generated, and will introduce proper dependencies as well - typing `make something_else` in a clean build dir will build `generator`, then run it, then build `something_else`.

Comment: After fixing the issues with the actual location of the generated files it works!

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell CMake that the files are generated:

```
set_source_files_properties(someautogeneratedfile.cpp PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
set_source_files_properties(someothergeneratedfile.h PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)
```

Now you just need to make sure that you run your **generator** before you run your **something_else** step. There are ways to manage that too, check out

```
add_custom_command(...)
add_custom_target(...)
add_dependencies(...)
```

Comment: There's no need to mark outputs of custom commands as `GENERATED`, CMake does that automatically. And there's no need to provide a custom target either, when the generator is also built by the project.